# write my own or choose a framework for link sharing website

Tags: php, mysql, frameworks

I'm a PHP programmer and I've done any projects based on PHP and MySQL without using any framework so far.

Now I'm going to create a big link sharing system (excel-able,modular,fast,theme based,secure etc.). But I have no experience to use any frameworks before. I need to know which is better to me.Choose a framework (easy to use and learn it fast) or still do my method?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: But I just need to know moving to frameworks is good for me with my experience or not.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would tell you to go with any of the frameworks. I personally feel good with `codeigniter` because I feel more comfortable with its level of documentations. There are several reasons why use frameworks. I would like list to few of them.

- MVC (model view controller) patterns. This actually keeps your model(data), view(templates or theme) and controller ( handle page requests and bind everything together) separate.
- Libraries and utilities. There are many things readily available to you. You should just use them. The documentations will probably help you a lot. So you don't have to reinvent the wheels.
- Security. There are many things available to you in php so that you can just use them to control some certain attacks. But still there are chances that you may miss something. In frameworks many things are done for you automatically. For an instance consider SQL injections.
- caching, benchmarks, profiling. These things may be readily available for you with frameworks. That's basically a performance related one.
- For a team work it great suits.

These are the things which I found good about frameworks. frameworks helps us write cleaner code. It is always a good thing to work on frameworks. Using frameworks will provide maintainability. I would recommend you codeigniter. But cakePHP is also fine. Have a look at [this](http://snook.ca/archives/php/codeigniter_vs_cakephp) link. There is a good comparison between those two frameworks. Hope this helps.